# Add refreshControl to a scrollView with pageControl

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol, uirefreshcontrol

As it can be seen in the gif from the link, I was able to add the refresh control to the scrollView but it is only shown for the first page. It still works for the other pages but it is not showing the refresh indicator which might be confusing for the user.
I have tried already a couple of ideas but nothing seems to work.
I am looking for a solution, which either only makes it possible to use the refresh control on the first page and disables vertical scrolling for the other pages or a solution which shows the refresh indicator at every page.

I would also like to disable the diagonal dragging. I added this in case there is a solution which solves both problems.

https://giphy.com/gifs/KfqJnVlwKE9fwFc07R/html5

Help will be very appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try using a `UIPageViewController` where each "page" has a scroll view that allows you to do your "drag-down-to-refresh" behavior.

Comment: When you "pull down to refresh" ... Do you want to pull down and update the content of an individual "card"? Or do you want to pull down al the cards and maybe update the number of cards shown? And maybe also update their contents?

Answer (score 0):

The indicator looks like it is probably added as a child of the scrollview, meaning it is scrolled along with the other contained views, and hence scrolled off-screen.

For an element you want to always be displayed over the scroll view add the indicator as a sibling of the scroll view (i.e. a subview of the scroll view's parent).